# vscode: how to clear both the console and the terminal using the same shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a shortcut that would clear the debug console + the terminal, and that would work when my cursor is on the editor.

I tried this code  in the keybindings.json which only works for the terminal, and when the cursor is on the terminal (unless I removed the "when" part). But in any case this doesn't clear the debug console.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction",
    "when": "inDebugRepl"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to use a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) that will allow you to run multiple commands.

In your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.clearTerminalandDebugConsole",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
      "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction"
    ]
  }
]
```

and in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+k",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.clearTerminalandDebugConsole" },
  // below since you wanted it to work with editor focus
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

You used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> but that is a sequence used in many already-bound conflicting commands, so I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: thanks but it a popup on the bottom says: `command 'multiCommand.clearTerminalandDebugConsole' not found`

Comment: Try reloading vscode after editing your settings.json and the keybindings.json.   I tested this and it works fine.  Or perhaps you forgot to save your changed settings before testing the keybinding?  That could cause that error message as well.

Comment: Or you might just have a typo. Try just searching for the setting in Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: @Mark I did not installed the extension (thought it was inbuilt). But it's now done. But I still have the same issue. But now the whole things is underlined in green in settings.json ( https://i.imgur.com/E8Ha9Ha.png ) Hover it says: `"This setting cannot be applied now. It will be applied when you open this folder directly."`

Comment: Are you using your user settings or workspace settings?  Try it in the user settings.json.  And are you in a multi-root workspace?

Comment: @Mark I don't really know, I use the C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My workspace folder\.vscode\settings.json (I only have a one workspace)

Comment: Try removing the comma at the end of `"workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction"`

Comment: You've got some other issue - I'll make a gif showing it working.  Did you put the multicommand.commands setting in your User settings - not workspace settings?